# how to 2d array bundle them together in my data

Tags: android, kotlin, arraylist

This is the structure of the 2d array I want.

```
[
   [
      "MyAdList()",
      "MyAdList()",
      "MyAdList()",
      "MyAdList()"
   ],
   [
      "MyAdList()",
      "MyAdList()",
      "MyAdList()"
   ]
]
```

The data received from the server is returned as MyAdList, and if the titles in it are the same, I would like to group them into a 2d array.
I tried tying it like this, but I know it's wrong. What should I do?

```
val testData: ArrayList<ArrayList<AdvertisingResponse.MyAdList>> = ArrayList()
                        for(i in 0 until it.responseData.myAdList.size) {
                            if(i == 0){
                                testData.add(it.responseData.myAdList)
                            } else if(it.responseData.myAdList[i].title == it.responseData.myAdList[i-1].title){
                                testData.add(it.responseData.myAdList)
                            }
                        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do

```
val testData = it.responseData.myAdList.groupBy { it.title }.values
```

Comment: Thanks. Before seeing this, I found and used the groupby function to solve it. Thank you so much for your interest!